# docker don't add new package in node_moudel nestJS project

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, nestjs

**my Dockerfile && docker-compose && docker log**

> my docker-compose

```
 admin:
build:
  context: ./src
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
command: npm run start:dev
container_name: nestjs
ports:
  - "8080:3000"
image: node:16
volumes:
  - ./src:/usr/src/app/src
  - ./src:/usr/src/app/src/node_modules
restart: always
tty: true
working_dir: /usr/src/app/src
```

my dockerfile
https://ibb.co/wWqDLCn

my dockerlog
https://ibb.co/f21S3dW

Comment: instead of `./src:/usr/src/app/src/node_modules` try just `/usr/src/app/src/node_modules`

Comment: What's the actual problem you're running into?  I'd recommend deleting the `volumes:` block entirely, so you're running the code built into the image, which could be related to the problem you reference in the title.

Comment: You are not using the node_modules installed in your Docker file as bind-mounts are mounted at run-time and not at build-time. So basically, you install the node dependencies, and then, after that, at run-time, you mount a folder over your previously installed node modules.